# Run Powershell script from Python?

Tags: python, powershell, usb

At the end of some processing in Python in Windows I am trying to eject an USB SD card.
Researching here it seems there are two ways in which to do it; call a PowerShell program or run PowerShell within Python.

Can anyone offer me any guidance. Please keep it simple; learning Python is my new year project.

So I have written a PowerShell script (ejectusb.ps1) which works perfectly:

```
$drive = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$drive.Namespace(17).Parsename("J:").InvokeVerb("Eject")
```

I then call it from Python using subprocess:

```py
subprocess.run(["E:\Data\Computing\Software\MicroSoft\Programming\Powershell\ejectusb.ps1"])
```

The SD card is not ejected and I get the error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Data/Computing/Software/Scripts/SdCardPlayEachVideo06.py", line 91, in <module>
subprocess.run(["E:\Data\Computing\Software\MicroSoft\Programming\Powershell\ejectusb.ps1"])
File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1493, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I don't understand this error message.

So I tried running PowerShell inside Python using:

```py
os.system('powershell $driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application; 
    $driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName("J:").InvokeVerb("Eject")')
```

An empty PowerShell screen and also what looks like a Windows command screen briefly flash up, but the SD card is not ejected. No error messages.

Can anyone offer me any guidance. Please keep it simple; learning Python is my new year project.

Comment: Some hints: 1.) try to search for the error you get online. 2.) read the documentation on `subprocess.run()`, especially how to pass a working directory (`cwd=`) and maybe also `shell`

Comment: Needs editing and clarification

Comment: Friedrich, thanks for the suggestions. I am still struggling to find a web page that describes subprocess in beginners terms. https://realpython.com/python-subprocess/ is reasonable but still uses terms I am not yet familiar with so is difficult to follow. Neither the 'Dummies Guide to Python' nor Deitel's "Python for Programmers" mention subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

Hamed's solution uses the argument 'powershell' to launch PowerShell. i.e
`subprocess.run(["powershell", "-File", "E:\Data\Computing\Software\MicroSoft\Programming\Powershell\ejectusb.ps1"])`

I have been using the full path to PowerShell as the argument, i.e
`subprocess.run(["C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", etc`
This path is correct (if I type it into the address bar of Windows File Explorer it launches PowerShell. But is causes a 'file not found' error.
So I dont know what the problem is with the full path but I am grateful for Hamed's workaround.

Comment: As suggested in 'Help', I have put back quotes ` around my code in the answer above but I am not sure that the formatting of code  is correct. Is there a better way?